# How to schedule a server start-up?

Tags: ubuntu, server

I have an ubuntu 14 server which I would like to be shut down for the next 10 hours, and then start up on its own.

I see we can schedule a reboot, but can we schedule a start event?

What I want is:

- server is on
- server goes to sleep for x hours, knowing it has to wake up after x hours
- server is asleep
- x hours pass
- server starts up on its own.

Is that possible?

Comment: AFAIK it is only possible to set a wake-up alarm in the BIOS, but not all support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command `rtcwake` that should do what you want. For example, to sleep your computer for 60 seconds, try `sudo rtcwake -u -s 60 -m mem`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have implemented, I have a home server that I want to run between 8am and 12am - I will not be using it while I am asleep. Below is a shell script that I have named simply *nap*, it takes a string that is a time in 24H format, and will wake the machine at that time using the *rtcwake* command.

When shutting down the system, just call `/bin/nap` instead of shutdown, and it will wake up at your defined time.

Combined with a cronjob that I have setup to run at midnight

```
0  0  *  *  *  root  /bin/nap
```

Since implementation, my server has had a better sleep / wake cycle then I.

The unfortunate part of this, is that if you power down your machine using the power button, it *will not* wake in the morning.

```
#!/bin/sh

# unix time in s that we should wake at
waketime=$(date +%s -d '08:00')

# make sure the time we got is in the future
if [ $(date +%s) -gt $waketime ]; then

        # if not add a day 60s * 60s * 24h
        waketime=$(($waketime + 86400))
fi

# time in S from now till then
dif=$(($waketime - $(date +%s)))

# tell the user
echo
echo "Current Time      :  $(date +%s)"
echo "Wake Time         :  $waketime"
echo "Seconds From Now  :  $dif"
echo
echo "Crtl-C to Cancel in 5s"
echo
sleep 5

# sleep with rtcwake
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off -l -s $dif

echo "Shutdown."
```